# Obtener ruta de una imagen seleccionada desde el explorador de archivos

Tags: java, android, imagen, android-sqlite

Necesito obtener la ruta donde está guardada la imagen al momento de que el usuario seleccione la imágen, tengo este código:

```
// Llamada al explorador de archivos
public void elegirFoto(View vista){
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    intent.setType("image/*");
    startActivityForResult(intent.createChooser(intent, "Elige una aplicación"),COD_SELECCIONA);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (requestCode){
        case COD_SELECCIONA:
            myPath = data.getData();
            Toast.makeText(this, String.valueOf(myPath), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;
    }
}

//Después guardo la ruta en la Base de Datos
```

Me arroja un resultado como:

> content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%643123

Pero la necesito algo así:

> /storage/emulated/carpeta/carpeta/carpeta/nombre_imagen.jpg

Ya que de la primera forma al guardarla en la base de datos y mostrarla después en image view no encuentra la ruta y de la segunda forma si, la forma en que muestro la imágen después es así:

```
resultado = BaseDeDatos.rawQuery("select img from artics where codigo = '"+codigoR+"'", null);
path = (resultado .getString(0));
bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
imgProducto.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Answer (score -1):

Hola aca te dejo un ejemplo de codigo con el que podes obtener el path tal como lo estas buscando y tambien el bitmap

```
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
   switch (requestCode){
      case COD_SELECCIONA:
         if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Uri uri = data.getData();
            String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(projection[0]);
            String path = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();

            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
            imgProducto.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
         }
         break;
      default:
         break;
   }
}
```

Comment: Ahm, se supone que el String filepath es la ruta ¿Verdad? Lo muestro en un Toast y no me sale ningún texto, ¿Hay algún error en él?
En Android Studio donde se utiliza cursor.moveToFirst() me muestra que podría ocasionar un java.length.NullPointerException()